# How can I setup Juju(MAAS/OpenStack) on two dedicated hosting servers?

Tags: server, cloud, juju, setup

I currently rent two dedicated hosting servers running both Ubuntu 12.04LTS (They are i5/i7 with 16GB of RAM).

I would love to turn these two in a pseudo public-cloud on where I could deploy stuff with juju. But I did not managed to find enough information on this :

- Is it possible to setup MAAS/Openstack when I do not own the network (would an openvpn solution work?).
- Does it mean that I must sacrifice one server to be the orchestra-master?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a minimum of 6 machines in order to set up OpenStack. However you can use one as a MAAS server to deploy the other one, but that wouldn't be a good use of that server.

These tools are more designed for larger deployments, and having a way to use them for one or two servers isn't really a use case we're aggressively pursuing with these tools, though there is a wishlist item for juju to deploy via normal vagrant-style virtual machines.